# Python: algorithm adding every nth element to list with collision check

Tags: python, list

I will apprecitate yout help with algorithm, that should loop through a *collection* of data and replace every *n-th* item basing on value check.

We have default list of *ints 0 values*. Then target, "**XXX**" string and *step* of insertion, *value 3* in this case.

Here's my code that basically works.

```
my_list = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
target = "XXX"
step = 3

for index, value in enumerate(my_list):
    if value == 0 and index % step == 0:
        my_list[index] = target

print(my_list)
```

Output is

```
'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX'
```

However, in case of something already is present on an list index, algorithm should check the collision and perform the same operation starting with the next free index. That's where I stuck.

Tried to do code below (changed my_list, elif added).

```
my_list_changed = ["AAA",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
target = "XXX"
step = 3

for index, value in enumerate(my_list_changed):
    if value == 0 and index % step == 0:
        my_list_changed[index] = target
    elif value != 0 and index % step ==0:
        index += 1
        my_list_changed[index] = target

print(my_list_changed)
```

Output

```
['AAA', 'XXX', 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX']
```

But it does not work how I wanted. It adds object on next free slot, but not keeps the step for the rest of the loop.

Algorithm should work also with different step values, since couple of operations such like above may be done on that one particular list collection.

I will apprecitate if you can improve my code.

If there are more pythonic ways to do that, I will be happy to learn them.

Edit:
Desired output should be like below. Parameter step = 3 and there is collision with 'AAA' at some point (index 6), so algorithm starts from next free slot (index 2) that allows it to finish the run with no collisions. 
Output:

```
['AAA', 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 'AAA', 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0]
```

Comment: Have you considered doing a while loop? That way you can control the indices you are currently visiting and not have to visit every index in the list.

Comment: `index += 1` inside the loop doesn't do what you think it's doing. You should keep a separate counter variable.

Comment: Please add a specific example of your desired result. There is confusion as you can see from the answers

Comment: What would you want `['AAA','AAA','AAA','AAA',0,0,0,0,0]` to end up as?

Comment: Given your comments on some of the answers you need to [edit] in a lot more specificity about what a correct answer should do.

Comment: Okay, thanks for comments and suggestions. Desired output should be like below. Parameter step = 3 and there is collision with 'AAA' at some point (index 6), so algorithm starts from next free slot (index 2) that allows it to finish the run with no collisions. Output: ['AAA', 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 'AAA', 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0]

Comment: For me, it still looks like 'XXX' appears every 3rd place not as you described. Please put some more input and expected output so it will be clear enough to help you.

Comment: Yep, it should appear every 3rd place but only, if there is no collision at any step of the collection. If there was no "AAA" at index 6, then algorithm would start mapping at index 1. But, since there is a "AAA" at idx 6, then it starts from index 2, since there is no collision when mapping on every 3rd step is performed. And that is desired behaviour. Hope I managed to be detailed right now.

Comment: If there is collision 'XXX' value should go next or before colliding element?
What output is correct for given input?
For example:
Input = ['AAA', 0, 0,           0, 0,         'AAA', 0,        0, 0,        0       ]
Out1 = ['AAA', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0,         'AAA', 0,        0, 'XXX', 0       ] or
Out2 = ['AAA', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0,         'AAA', 'XXX', 0, 0,        'XXX'] 
or some different?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I guess the collision detection should be done before mapping, so if there is any "AAA" at some possible 3rd step, the start index should be +1 (or more, until clear path is found). For Input = ['AAA', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'AAA', 0, 0, 0, 0 ] Output should be: ['AAA', "XXX", 0, 0, "XXX", 'AAA', 0, "XXX", 0, 0], since when we start at index 1 and move every 3rd step, no 'AAA' on the route.

Comment: So @Karl has post below correct answer for this problem. Mark his answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks, one issue. If collision found it should not map "XXX" on index +1 or index -1 from "AAA", but instead it should:
a) determine the first free index from beginning of collection, that allows to map "XXX" without collision for all possible n steps
b) map the "XXX" every n-th step
Above solution with Input = INPUT ["AAA",0,"AAA","AAA","AAA",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] returns Output = ['AAA', 'XXX', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0] but Expected is = ['AAA', 0, 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0] - mapping only from index 5 allows no collision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python when you are looping through a collection using a for loop, you cannot modify the index currently being iterated through like you have done with `index += 1` (Similar to for each loops in other languages). To control the indices, the easiest way to do it is by using a while loop instead.

This example avoids collisions by trying the next possible index:

```
my_list_changed = ["AAA",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
target = "XXX"
step = 3

index = 0
while index < len(my_list_changed):
    if my_list_changed[index] == 0:
        my_list_changed[index] = target
        index += step
    else:
        index += 1

print(my_list_changed)
# ['AAA', 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0]
```

Edit: After further explanation of the expected output, it seems that this algorithm is actually supposed to first find the minimum starting index that allows you to traverse the list by steps without any collisions. This can be done by first trying to find this valid `start_index` and then use it to change the values as you traverse the list by steps.

```
my_list_changed = ["AAA",0,0,0,"AAA",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
target = 'XXX'
step = 3    

start_index = None
cur_index = 0
# Attempt traversal at each starting index
while cur_index < len(my_list_changed):
    index = cur_index
    # While current attempt hasn't reached end of list
    while index < len(my_list_changed):
        if my_list_changed[index] == 0:
            index += step
        else:
            break  # Stop traversal because invalid
    if index >= len(my_list_changed):
        start_index = cur_index  # Found our valid start_index
        break
    cur_index += 1

# If found a valid path, then change the values
if start_index is not None:
    while start_index < len(my_list_changed):
        my_list_changed[start_index] = target
        start_index += step

print(my_list_changed)
# ['AAA', 0, 'XXX', 0, 'AAA', 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0]
```

There is some downsides to a brute force approach like this, since a lot of indices will be retried in the worst case where it has to attempt every possible starting index even if it is not possible to find an attempt without collisions.

Comment: It's not a correct answer (same error as Håken Lid). If any 3rd element will be different than 0 output will be invalid because of 'idx += 1. It will then start not from n+3` element but with n+1+3 element.

Comment: How do you know it's not correct? OP never really specified what happens in a collision other then "algorithm should check the collision and perform the same operation starting with the next free index". That could mean restart the step calculation from the collision index + 1, or it could mean how you are saying where it only is looking for 3rd element indices.

Comment: Take a look at the second output and run your code against second `my_list` input and compare.

Comment: I'd say it's pretty clear from the OP this is the expected behavior: his example bad output is given as an example of how it shouldn't look: "But it does not work how I wanted."

Comment: Thanks for answers. The algorigthm should start with first free slot and then goes every n-th step. Default collection may be much bigger than in examples in question, and there might be operations with different steps run on it.

Comment: @YggY Yes this while loop handles any size collection or step value

Comment: Additional comment. When loop is performed inserts of "XXX" element should be strict for every n-th index starting from the first free one. If later in the collection (bigger one)there will collision occur, the whole process shoud be skipped and started from the beginning (on another first free slot), so that in result every interval between added "XXX"s is exact n starting from the first instert in current loop.

Comment: @YggY: how is that different from this answer? You should include expected output in the question text. Prose descriptions are typically  not specific enough or ambiguous.

Comment: Okay, thanks for comments and suggestions. Desired output should be like below. Parameter step = 3 and there is collision with 'AAA' at some point (index 6), so algorithm starts from next free slot (index 2) that allows it to finish the run with no collisions. Output: ['AAA', 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 'AAA', 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0]

Comment: That does it. Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
my_list = ['NO!',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
target = "XXX"
step = 3
```

You can use [slice assignment](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) with a [ternary](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/):

```
my_list[::step]=[target if item==0 else item for item in my_list[::step]]
>>> my_list
['NO!', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX']
```

---

Given the several comments, I *think* you are looking for 1) test if the insertion of 'XXX' every three elements is possible without collision; 2) move over 1 element and try again if not. (Now you need to define how far over you should step, but it is a different problem than originally described)

If I got that right, you can still use slice assignment. You just need to add a mechanism to test and add an offset:

```
def f(my_list, offset=0, step=3):
    while offset<len(my_list):
        if any(item!=0 for item in my_list[offset::step]):
            offset+=1
        else:
            my_list[offset::step]=[target for item in my_list[offset::step]]
            break
    return my_list
```

Test that:

```
for i in range(13):
    l=[0]*13
    l[i]='AAA'
    print '{} => {}'.format(l,f(l[:]))
```

Prints:

```
['AAA', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => ['AAA', 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0]
[0, 'AAA', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => ['XXX', 'AAA', 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX']
[0, 0, 'AAA', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => ['XXX', 0, 'AAA', 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX']
[0, 0, 0, 'AAA', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => [0, 'XXX', 0, 'AAA', 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 'AAA', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => ['XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 'AAA', 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'AAA', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => ['XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 'AAA', 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'AAA', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => [0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 'AAA', 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'AAA', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => ['XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 'AAA', 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'AAA', 0, 0, 0, 0] => ['XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 'AAA', 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'AAA', 0, 0, 0] => [0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 'AAA', 'XXX', 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'AAA', 0, 0] => ['XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 'AAA', 0, 'XXX']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'AAA', 0] => ['XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 'AAA', 'XXX']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'AAA'] => [0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 0, 'XXX', 0, 'AAA']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
idx = 0
while idx < len(my_list):
    if my_list[idx] == 0:
        my_list[idx] = target
        idx += step
    else:
        idx += 1
```

Comment: It's not a correct answer. If any 3rd element will be different than 0 output will be invalid because of 'idx += 1`. It will then start not from `n+3` element but with `n+1+3` element.

Comment: Yeah. I believe that's what the asker wanted.

Comment: No. Take a look at the second output and run your code against second `my_list` input and compare.

Comment: That's not how I understand the question. The second output is what their current code produces, not what they want. I think you should let the asker give feedback instead. Or submit your own answer based on how you read the question.